# Handling waiting for a callback with data (from another server, receiving undefined vars)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

**UPDATE**: I am currently researching and trying to implement this using a Promise. It isn't working just yet but I believe I am getting close.  If anyone has any input about a Promise is a better way to go than settimeout I would appreciate your feedback.

I am currently using the [feedsub](https://www.npmjs.org/package/feedsub) module that reads an rss feed and sends the data back to my app.

Currently my code looks like:

```
var reader = new FeedSub('http://pathtosite/atom.xml', {
        emitOnStart: true
    });                 

reader.read(function(err,items){
                atomXMLposts = items;
                console.log(atomXMLposts);
});
```

The `reader.read` accepts a callback function that runs when it receives the items argument.

the `console.log(atomXMLposts)` logs the items in an array, which is what I want. But...

When I run this block of code right after:

```
atomXMLposts.forEach(function(post){
                // console.log(post["published"]);
                var now = moment(post["published"]);
                console.log(now);
            })
```

I receive an error saying `TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined`

I believe this is a result of of the function running before `atomXMLposts` is assigned the values. So I wrapped a setTimeout around this code block.

```
setTimeout(function(){

    // if(atomXMLposts)
    atomXMLposts.forEach(function(post){
        // console.log(post["published"]);
        var now = moment(post["published"]);
        console.log(now);
    })
}, 2500);
```

This returns values but I personally feel using setTimeout is not a good practice.  The 2500 ms I added is an arbitrary number I `guesstimated`.  What would be a better way of handling this? Is there a better way? I am trying to search for a better alternative, when I search `using setTimeout to wait for parameters` or something to that nature, I am not receiving anything that is useful.

Comment: You could just use `0` for the `setTimeout()` function. No need in unnecessary delay.

Comment: When it is 0, atomXMLposts is undefined, it needs time to be populated and be sent the RSS feed data.

Comment: You've tested this? It should still be an asynchronous call.

Comment: My current code works with the 2500ms,when I insert `0` I get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: Gotcha, sometimes my brain only functions half the time :/

Comment: Ultimately what you asked is, should you use setTimeout, and the answer is that it's perfectly fine. You could use your own wrapper function also.

Comment: What would happen if the request took more than 2.5 seconds? It would still be undefined.  I am currently researching and trying to learn how to implement a promise.  From what I am reading this is the better way to go but still not 100% sure.

Comment: You should just place the code inside the `reader.read(function(err,items){` callback instead of a timeout callback. If you want, you can also use promises on top of that.